# Invoke other method instead

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have two methods and one of them with an annotation, let's say:

```
@ReplacingMethod(bar)
public void foo() { ... }

public void bar { ... }
```

Is it possible to invoke bar instead of foo whenever foo is called, without jumping into the body of foo? I did some research on this and were not able to set a return value via reflections. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does @ReplacingMethod look like? When I googled for that, I only found this SO question.

Comment: There's no standard feature to do this in Java, but you might be able to do this using an [aspect-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) framework such as [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) or [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), e.g. with [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). I don't think you can change method implementation in pure Java without AOP.

Let me give you an example how to achieve what you asked for with Spring AOP. First, define your annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ReplacingMethod {
    String value();
}
```

Then define an *aspect* that will do the actual replacing of method:

```
@Aspect // aspect is a module encapsulating your replacing functionality
public class ReplacingAspect {
    // pointcut gives an expression selecting the "joint points" to be intercepted
    @Pointcut("@annotation(example.annotation.ReplacingMethod)")
    public void methodToBeReplaced() { }

    // advice defining the code executed at joint points selected by given pointcut;
    // in our case @Around is executed instead of the method call selected by pointcut methodToBeReplaced()
    @Around("methodToBeReplaced()")
    public void replaceMethodCall(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        // get reference to the method to be replaced
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();
        // extract the name of the method to be called from ReplacingMethod annotation
        ReplacingMethod replacingMethodAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(ReplacingMethod.class);
        String methodToCallName = replacingMethodAnnotation.value();
        // use reflection to call the method
        Method methodToCall = pjp.getTarget().getClass().getMethod(methodToCallName);
        methodToCall.invoke(pjp.getTarget());
    }
}
```

Now, assuming you have class `TestClass` where you have applied your `@ReplacingMethod` annotation,

```
public class TestClass {
    @ReplacingMethod("bar")
    public void foo() { System.out.println("foo"); }
    public void bar() { System.out.println("bar"); }
}
```

the last missing piece is to get create your instance of `TestClass` with AOP enabled and your `ReplacingAspect` applied:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfiguration.class);  // create Spring context that enables AOP under the hood
        TestClass testObject = context.getBean(TestClass.class); // we get reference to TestClass instance from context; calling on a plain new instance wouldn't work
        testObject.foo(); // prints "bar" !
    }

    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy // enables AOP support
    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfiguration {
        @Bean public TestClass testClass() { return new TestClass(); }
        @Bean public ReplacingAspect aspect() { return new ReplacingAspect(); } // enables our ReplacingAspect
    }
}
```

You can check out the whole working example at [GitHub](https://github.com/mifeet/stack-overflow-examples/tree/master/aop-invoke-method).

Answer (score 0):

Reflection cannot change the schema of a class and not its behaviour. It can only call (possibly hidden) features.

If you want to replace a method call by another try out a byte code library as [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) or [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/). These tools allow you to change class definitions and behaviour (even at runtime with some restrictions).

The approach with AOP is easier, but it is not as flexible and its classpath footprint is larger.